# Samsung Remote Test Lab application blocked by Java

Tags: java, samsung-mobile

I'm trying to get Samsung Remote Test Lab working on my Windows 8 machine, but I get an error whenever I try to run their JNPL file downloaded from the site:

```
"Application Blocked by Security Settings" : "Your security settings have blocked a self-signed application from running"
```

I've looked at adding an exception in the Java security settings, but don't know what address to specify in the exception.

Anyone come across this problem or suggestions on how to get around it?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on Mac.
I "solved" it by going to `System Preferences -> Java -> Security` and changing `Security Level` from **High** to **Medium**.

The other solution explained [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml) would be adding the URL to the exception list.
The URL would be `http://img-developer.samsung.com` I think, I haven't tried that though.